# Array with type Class.field []

Tags: java, arrays, oop

could you please suggest how i can use array of fields of a paticular class

for exaple:

```
public class Student {

    private String fio;
    private double rating;
    private double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
}
```

In class Group i want to return an array of rating which is in Student class

```
public class Group {

private Student[] students;
public double[] ratingarray(){

    return students.getRating() ;
}
```

Comment: `getRating()` should be `public`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to iterate through all the class objects and create an array with all the ratings.

So something like below in the function `ratingarray()` :

```
double[] ratings = new double[students.length];
for(int i=0;i<students.length;i++){
     ratings[i]=students[i].getRating();
}
return ratings;
```

Comment: @"Siya Ntombela" ... sorry but your edit would make the compiler fail, as the array object has a length instead of a size(). That's the reason I declined it. .. of course if it were an ArrayList or a Vector etc, we could've used the size() instead ... I'd suggest you try the code yourself before suggesting :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no quick ways around this. You will have to make the array yourself:

```
public double[] ratingarray(){
    double[] ratings = new double[students.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
        ratings[i] = students[i].getRating();
    }
    return ratings;
}
```

As additional info, you can design it differently!
Whenever you are add a `Student` to the `Group`, you can in addition to adding it to the array of students, add the `student.getRating()` to a `private double[] ratings` variable as well!

Comment: There is a shortcut in Java 8: `return Arrays.stream(students).mapToDouble(Student::getRating).toArray()`

Comment: *you can design it better...* highly debatable.

Comment: I think this is out of OP's scope, hence the 'easy' solution. But you are right of course =)

Comment: I was just about to change it to 'differently' as better is definately not the right word. All depends on how often you want those ratings I suppose and whether or not you want them coupled to the student

Answer (score 0):

You've to make a method which does it, like this

```
public double[] ratingarray(){
  double[] ratings=new double[students.length];
  for(int i=0;i< students.length;i++){
    ratings[i]=students[i].getRating();
  }
  return ratings;
```

}

Then correct the syntax errors in your code..

Answer (score 0):

You can use J8 lambda expressions

`Arrays.stream(inA).map(obj -> obj.getBar()).toArray(String[]::new)`

or

`Arrays.stream(inA).map(obj -> obj.getBar()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Full code here:

```
public static class Foo {
    private final int foo;
    private final String bar;

    public Foo(final int foo, final String bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Foo[] inA = new Foo[2];
    inA[0] = new Foo(1, "a");
    inA[1] = new Foo(2, "b");

    //to Array
    final String[] resA = Arrays.stream(inA).map(obj -> obj.getBar()).toArray(String[]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resA));
    //to List
    final List<String> resL = Arrays.stream(inA).map(obj -> obj.getBar()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(resL);
}
```